# How to set firefox search back to google

Tags: firefox, search-engines

The latest version of [firefox now has Yahoo as it's search instead of Google](http://www.cnet.com/news/in-major-shift-firefox-to-use-yahoo-search-by-default-in-us/). I don't like this, I want to change it back to Google - how?

I have already tried setting the keyword.URL in about:config to http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q= already, but this isn't working on the search that is performed when I open a new tab (blank) and type something into the box.

Comment: @Dave none of those had an accepted answer that was NOT about:config keyword.URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change by FireFox angered me enough that I wondered if I should stop using it.  I still prefer it over chrome tho.  I'm not so much a Google lover, but I don't think Firefox should be making that change on my behalf.

To change my settings back, I simply clicked the magnifying glass icon at the left end of the search box, and selecting "Change Search Settings" which lead me directly to `Tools` > `Options` > `Search`, where I reselected my favorite default search engine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's actually one I used since although the others would probably work as well, I have already removed the dedicated "search box" and just use the URL bar

Answer (score 2):

This can be set by clicking the little arrow in front of the search toolbar (location depends on your custom settings). There you can either choose a preset engine or add an own search engine.

..but please, take back the "*I wish it was a virus*"

[image: Search toolbar with duckduckgo]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works to simply select google from the dropdown in Firefox's search bar.

If this does not work for you, try following [this guide](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-remove-yahoo-as-firefoxs-default-search-engine/) for a more thorough step-by-step solution.

Answer (score 0):

Type the below in Firefox browser:

```
about:preferences#search
```

You will get Default Search Engine dropdown. It will have a list of search engines.

Select "Google" and you are done with the task!

Mozilla Firefox Sceenshot for getting back to Google Search Engine:

[image: Mozilla Firefox Sceenshot for getting back to Google Search Engine]